# Ajax Error on Loading Datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

**I am currently trying to load a data table from my controller, and this Ajax Error appears**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLr1V.jpg)

```
function InitOverviewDataTable() {
                $("#data-table").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                $('#data-table').dataTable({
                    bProcessing: true,
                    sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("LoadUser", "Setup")'
                });
            }


 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadUser()
        {
            var users = db.R_User.ToList()
              .Select(a => new
              {
                  employee_number = a.employee_number,
                  role_id = a.role_id,
                  active_status = a.active_status
              });
            return Json(users);
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The first thing to do is follow the troubleshooting steps at the URL provided in the error.  What are the results of following the steps?